# Why do I get "Function was not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c, sdl

This problem occurred when I was trying to create a graphical window in C, following an SDL2 tutorial.
I created the headers, the source .c and the main as in the tutorial, but when I run it with make, only the .o of the source files are created and when I go to the main, it says that the functions are not declared.

el error es el siguiente:

```
PS C:\Juego> make
g++ -c -I src/include -L src/lib -o main draw.c -o draw.o
g++ -c -I src/include -L src/lib -o main init.c -o init.o
g++ -c -I src/include -L src/lib -o main input.c -o input.o
g++ -c -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.c -o main.o
main.c: En la función 'int SDL_main(int, char**)':
main.c:12:9: error: 'initSDL' no fue declarado en este ámbito        
   12 | initSDL();
      | ^~~~~~~
main.c:18:17: error: 'prepareScene' no fue declarado en este ámbito  
   18 | prepareScene();
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:20:17: error: 'doInput' no fue declarado en este ámbito       
   20 | doInput();
      | ^~~~~~~
main.c:22:17: error: 'presentScene' no fue declarado en este ámbito  
   22 | presentScene();
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [makefile:18: main.o] Error 1
```

and the makefile is:

```
# Compiler and flags
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -I src/include -L src/lib -o main

# Source files and object files
SRC = draw.c init.c input.c main.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

# Libraries to link
LIBS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

# Build the executable
main: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

# Compile source files to object files
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# Clean up
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) main
```

and the main.c

```
#include "structs.h"
#include"SDL2\SDL.h"

#define main SDL_main



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    memset(&app, 0, sizeof(App));

    initSDL();

    atexit(cleanup);

    while (1)
    {
        prepareScene();

        doInput();

        presentScene();

        SDL_Delay(16);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile the files individually, but it did not work.  And just changing the way I write the makefile did not work either.

Comment: Are there header files you should be including in `main.c` like `draw.h` and `init.h`? Also not sure what you mean with `#define main SDL_main` but this seems wrong.

Comment: `\S` is an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The C standard does not specify that the quoted string in a `#include` directive is processed the way a string literal is, with the escape sequences that it specifies for a string literal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, ok! Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @EricPostpischil 6.4.7.3: _"if the characters `’`,  ```\``` , `//`, or `/*` occur in the sequence between the `"` delimiters, the behavior is undefined."_ seems to say it's UB though, or does that just mean that it's up to the implementation?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yes. It is up to the implementation anyway, since the C standard cannot specify file name or path formats for specific operating systems, and 6.10.2 leaves that up to the implementation. Windows uses a backward slash in its paths, so a C implementation on it is likely to either accept a backward slash in a `#include` or map forward slash characters to backward slashes. In any case, this does not seem to be a problem for OP.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I had a feeling that would be it :-)

Comment: On topic: `SDL_Init` is the correct name, not `initSDL`.

Comment: The path for SDL headers (SDL2) and that told to compiler (src/include) don't match. SDL files can't be found, unless you have a nasty location for them (e.g. same dir as your code). And to avoid "\" possible issue prefer "SDL2/SDL.h"

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo the 'initSDL' is funtion that i created, just to set up the window and so on, is not a funtion of the SDL library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declarations for the functions that `main` calls must be present in the source file containing the definition of `main`, either directly or indirectly via `#include` directives.

If there are declarations of those functions in header files (typically files named `name.h`, then insert directives of the form `#include name.h` in `main.c` to include those directives. If there are not declarations of those functions in header files, then either write declarations in `main.c` or put them in header files and include those.

Comment: it worked to call the functions from the headers, I had a problem there because 2 headers called to another one, and an error was created there, I combined them and it was solved, it worked.
Now I have the doubt, is it better to have only one main.c and many custom .h or several .c?